# Android - Simple framework parser to ignore elements?

Tags: android, simple-framework

I am using `SimpleXML` attached to `Retrofit`. My XML item looks like this:

```
<item id="1-22-33-55" parentID="1" restricted="1">
        <res protocolInfo="http-get:*:video/mpeg:*">http://<blablahere>/slash/slash</res>
        <upnp:callSign>Channel</upnp:callSign>
        <upnp:channelID type="ANALOG">1</upnp:channelID>
        <upnp:channelID type="DIGITAL">1,0</upnp:channelID>
        <upnp:channelID type="SI">1,1019,10301</upnp:channelID>
        <upnp:channelID type="UNIVERSAL">578865282</upnp:channelID>
        <upnp:class>object.item.videoItem.videoBroadcast</upnp:class>
        <dc:title>Channel</dc:title>
    </item>
```

**But,** I don't want to parse `callSign`. If I **intentionally** ommit this from my POJO, I get the exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'callSign' does not have a match in class xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.ContentDirectoryChannelItem at line 1
```

Is there a way to specify which Element specifically to **ignore** when parsing?

My POJO:

```
public class ContentDirectoryChannelItem {

  @Attribute(name = "id")
  private String chanId;

  @Attribute(name = "parentID")
  private String parentID;

  @Attribute(name = "restricted")
  private String restricted;

  @ElementMap(entry = "channelID", key = "type", attribute = true, inline = true)
  private Map<String, String> channelIDmap;

  @Element(name = "class")// I want this out also !!!
  private String upnpClass;

  @Element(name = "title")
  private String dcTitle;

  @ElementMap(entry = "res", key = "protocolInfo", attribute = true, inline = true)
  private Map<String, String> resourceMap;
 }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Reference to http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#loosemap

I did 2 changes:

1). Specified all `@Root` elements that should have `strict = false`.

```
@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
```

2). The `Retrofit instance` converter factory was created `nonStrict`:

```
.addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict())
```